# Dependent width on width of other elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li>ITEM</li>
  <li>CONTACT</li>
  <li><input type="text" placeholder="Zoeken..."></li>
  <li><img alt="shopCart" id="shopCart" href="image.jpg"></img></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul{
    height: 125px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    margin: 31px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Android ≤ 2.3, iOS ≤ 4 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox ≤ 28 */
        box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, Firefox 29+, IE 8+, Opera, Safari 5.1 */
}
```

Now I want the width of `li:nth-last-child(2)` to depend on the width of the other elements. Like the ul is for example 1000px in width, the first, second and last li are together 300px witdth, I then want my `nth-last-child(2)` to be 700px in width.

So basically I want my `li:nth-last-child(2)` to be 60%-(width of other li's)

**Edit:**
`width: calc(60% - 700px);` would be a possibility, but I how do I find out the width of all the other li's?

JS is possible too

Comment: How should I do this width JS?

Comment: please google for that, I don't know properly, or tag this question as javascript....

Comment: have you tried using the table & table-cell method?

Comment: I didn't, actually. You mean an HTML table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in CSS:

```
ul{
    height: 125px;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;

}

li{
    display:table-cell;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    margin: 31px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Android ≤ 2.3, iOS ≤ 4 */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /* Firefox ≤ 28 */
        box-sizing: border-box; /* Chrome, Firefox 29+, IE 8+, Opera, Safari 5.1 */
}

li:nth-last-child(2){
   width:100%;
}
```

The last bit is the important part. It tells the 3rd item to take up as much space as possible.

Comment: I like this solution, but I noticed it's not really compatible in older browsers. What's another solution?

Comment: @Grafit can you define 'older'? The only part that should cause issues is the `nth-last-child`, which I referenced from your question. There are other ways, like adding a class to the search `li` and targeting that.

Comment: Nevermind, in a JSFiddle this works, I'll try to implement this

Comment: Is it possible to make the height as high as the text?

Comment: @Grafit you are setting the height in the `ul` to `height: 125px`. If you remove that the height will be reduced to that of the content + padding